# Python 3 UTF-8 bug on Widows?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, utf-8

I am trying to print from Python 3 HTML that includes utf-8 characters. The program below works fine with Python 2 and with Python 3 on Macs and Linux. But on Windows I have to delete the line `<meta charset='UTF-8'>` for utf characters to show correctly. I tried using # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- but that didn't help either.
Is this a bug in Python 3?

```
print( "Content-type: text/html;\n")
print( """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head><body>
    <p>¡Hola Señor Müller!</p>
</body></html>
""")
```

Comment: `print` defaults to writing text to `sys.stdout`, which defaults to encoding text with the encoding returned by `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. In Windows, this is the active codepage of the process, which defaults to the system encoding, which defaults to the ANSI codepage of the system locale. In Windows 10, the active codepage of a process can be set to UTF-8 in the application manifest, but python.exe doesn't set this. Windows 10 also allows setting the system encoding to UTF-8, but it's not enabled by default. So the preferred encoding is probably the ANSI codepage of your system locale.

Comment: Thank you. What is the best work-around for this?

Comment: Print to what?  The terminal used matters.  It works fine pasting the above into `cmd.exe` running Python 3 for example.  Is it a CGI script? Environment matters.  Is it failing or just printing incorrectly?  Traceback?

Comment: this program is being passed to the Apache websever for execution. it works, but the utf characters come out as question marks

Comment: @MarkTolonen, I assumed stdout is redirected to a file or pipe, rather than to a console (i.e. conhost.exe with python.exe as a client -- not cmd.exe). It's unlikely that someone would write HTML to a console just to copy and paste it into a file to display in a web browser.

Comment: @ErykSun Yes, and that's why I asked for clarification before writing an answer.

Comment: I should have said 'the CGI script below' rather than program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` is not sending the data encoded as UTF-8, although that's what you have declared.  For a CGI script, you can override the `stdout` default encoding with:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: In the environment, you can also set `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` to use UTF-8 for the `sys.std*` files. In 3.7+ there's also UTF-8 mode for all I/O via `PYTHONUTF8=1`.